# Rails - Join query difficulties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have two basic models: **Stadium** and **Owner**

The relations between those two models are:

A **Stadium**:

```
belongs_to :owner
```

An **Owner**:

```
has_many :stadiums
```

The thing here is, an Owner has also Categories associated, and here is where **owner_category** model comes in.

An **Owner**:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :owner_categories,
                          :join_table => 'l_owners_owner_categories',
```

And **OwnerCategory**:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :owners, :join_table => 'l_owners_owner_categories'
```

Basically,

The OwnerCategory table looks like this:

```
id,name
1,sport
2,kids
```

So, my question is:

Given that I let the user to choose a **City** and a **Category**, how would I get all the **Stadiums** from that city which **Owner** has the given **Category**?

So for example:

If I have the following Stadiums:

```
id,name,city,owner_id
1,'soccer stadium','New York',5
2,'music stadium','New York',4
2,'music stadium','San Francisco',4
```

The following Owners:

```
id,name
4, 'John'
5, 'Peter'
```

The following OwnersCategories table:

```
id,name,description
1,'sports','this category is associated with stadiums that support sports'
2,'music','this category is associated with stadiums that support music'
```

And the following join table:

```
owner_id,owner_category_id
 5, 1
```

When the users chooses 'New York' and 'Sports' it should give this stadium:

```
 1,'soccer stadium','New York',5
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be Owner has_many :stadiums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (warning: not tested):

```
Stadium.joins(:owner).joins(:owner => :owner_categories)
.where(:city => "New York").where("owners_categories.name = ?", "sports")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Stadium < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :for_city, lambda { |city_name| where(:city => city_name) }
  scope :for_owner_category,
        lambda { |owner_category_id|
          joins("INNER JOIN owners ON owners.id = stadium.owner_id" +
                " INNER JOIN l_owners_owner_categories ON l_owners_owner_categories.owner_id = owners.id").
          where("l_owners_owner_categories.owner_category_id = :category_id",
                :category_id => owner_category_id)
        }
end

Stadium.for_city("New York").for_owner_category(1)
```

Comment: when trying to create the second scope it says "Can't create a Proc withouth a block..."

Comment: it needs curly braces, and won't take do ... end.  Answer edited.